# build localized installer with wix but use arbitrary characters for file names

Tags: unicode, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to build localized Japanese installers using Wix 3.0, but having trouble including files that have characters that are not compatible with the active -cultures flag.

For example, I am trying to use 'ja-jp' as a culture, but the installer build process chokes on the 'μ' symbol, as it is used in a file name that is included in the installer. I've tried using the code page for the UTF-8 variant of Unicode (65001) in the wxl file, but when I do this, I am unable to set a culture, so the installer dialogs do not get localized/translated.

Also, it isn't clear to me if I need to manually translate the installer dialog strings in the .wxl file, or if simply using 'ja-jp' (for example) will automatically translate the basic installer dialog text, pulling from the included WixUIExtension.dll. I know that if there are any custom strings/dialogs, I'd need to specify those, but for now I just want to get the basics working. I'll move on to custom components and the EULA later.

The basic call to light.exe is like this:

```
-nologo -cultures:ja-jp -loc unicode.wxl -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension
```

and unicode.wxl looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Codepage="65001" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
</WixLocalization>
```

The error is something like this:

> error LGHT0311: A string was provided with characters that are not
>   available in the specified database code page '932'. Either change
>   these characters to ones that exist in the database's code page, or
>   update the database's code page by modifying one of the following
>   attributes: Product/@Codepage, Module/@Codepage, Patch/@Codepage,
>   PatchCreation/@Codepage, or WixLocalization/@Codepage.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15916923/600559

Comment: Hi Morten, thanks so much. I saw this and it helped me get part way with using the unicode Codepage. Part of my problem was solved by updating wix, but it looks like i'm still unable to get full unicode file names AND get the ja-jp culture. Maybe there is a way to just use the ja-jp for installer dialog language purposes. Running some tests today...Again, thanks for taking a look!